# Can't locate loadable object for module Image::Magick

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have installed Image::Magick in perl. See below install window. But displayed error "Can't locate loadable object for module Image::Magick". Please find the solution.

### Install Window:

```
cpan[1]> install Image::Magick
?[32mReading 'C:\Documents and Settings\sukumar.s\Local Settings\Application Dat
a\.cpan\Metadata'?[0m
?[32m  Database was generated on Tue, 05 Nov 2013 20:53:02 GMT?[0m
?[32mImage::Magick is up to date (6.86).?[0m
?[32m?[0m
```

### Error Window:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module Image::Magick in @INC (@INC contains: C:
/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at e:\1.pl line 2.
Compilation failed in require at e:\1.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at e:\1.pl line 2.
```

### My Program:

```
use strict;
use Image::Magick;
print "Image::Magick is processing ... \n";
```

### Cmd: cpan force install Image::Magick (Error)

```
            Magick.xs:14062: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
            Magick.xs:14069: error: `UndefinedException' undeclared (first use in this funct
            ion)
            Magick.xs: In function `boot_Image__Magick':
            Magick.xs:2384: error: `MagickFalse' undeclared (first use in this function)
            Magick.xs:2388: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
            dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'Magick.o'
            ?[32m  JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz?[0m
            ?[31m  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK?[0m
            ?[32mRunning make test?[0m
            ?[32m  Can't test without successful make?[0m
            ?[32mRunning make install?[0m
            ?[32m  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible?[0m
```

S. Sukumar

Answer (score 2):

Which Perl distribution are you using? [`PerlMagick`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ejcristy/PerlMagick-6.87/Magick.pm) runs out of the box with active state ppm.

If you use another distribution you can install this module
by downloading the sources for the Windows version of
[ImageMagick (Download Area)](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows). Unpack the binaries and type

```
cd ImageMagick-.../PerlMagick
perl Makefile.net
nmake
nmake install
```

You can find more information about installing it [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php).

The [ImageMagick troubleshooting forum](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=7) may help you.

Comment: "PerlMagick needs ActiveState Perl in require" - I'm not really sure what you're trying to say here, but I'm pretty certain that you're wrong. I've successfully used PerlMagick on many versions of Perl that weren't ActivePerl.

Comment: you are right! i want to say that with active state ppm ImageMagick works right out of the box. with other distributions you have to do the way is described above.

Answer (score 1):

Your installation of `Image::Magick` is up to date but incomplete. The Perl part of the module is unable to find the binary component.

You should reinstall `Image::Magick` using

```
cpan force install Image::Magick
```

and report back with any errors if they occur.

Comment: Installing imagemagick from CPAN never works. As far as I can tell it's only there so that the docs will be on s.c.o. even though they're not even the good docs ;)

Comment: @hobbs: It has worked fine for me on both Windows 7 and Debian. If you know a procedure to get it installed then please post an answer.